# Get domain and subdomain from $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] (or other way)

Tags: php

I'm using: `$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"];` to get: `sub1.host.com.ar`

How can I get 'sub1' and 'host' from `$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"];`/ is there any simpler way to echo them?

Comment: yes, it just get's a key named path with the full url.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using

```
$parts=explode('.', $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]);
```

you can split it by the dots.

Answer (score 2):

give meaningful names and break array in one line:

```
list($first,$host) = explode(".",$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]);
echo $host;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$exp = explode('.', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
print_r($exp);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use the explode function it will create an array from your url string, once you get an array, you can navigate and get your desired element from it.

for the first name, you can use the following code.

```
echo array_shift((explode(".",$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])));
```

Comment: Don't know the reason for voting it down.

Comment: Possibly because the error, can only pass variables by reference, that results in using your code on newer versions of PHP

Comment: It will work from 5.5. So now a days most of the web servers are 5.5 and above. So i think this is not a problem. It will work like charm.

Comment: I disagree, the documentation should clear up any confusion http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php